# HR Libraries Scenario >> Employee libraries and security via AD

Tags: 2013, document-library, security

We have a scenario in 2013 where we are proposing a library per employee to hold HR documents.  We'd have a dropoff library that would route the document to the proper library which is based off the employee's name, and then apply permissions for that employee's manager to have contribute access...looking at AD possibly/hopefully.

The employee themselves would have "Read Only" in this scenario to their HR library, just their manager and managers on up the chain would have contribute access.

Anyone dealt with this yet?

We are also looking at a process to automate the actual library creation when an employee is a new hire.

Any feedback/suggestions are welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Content router start to look good - but having to predifine your rules or create a solution to automate that might be more than you need.

I would consider something like the following (bear in mind this is quick first pass at your problem and will probably need to be tweaked):

1. Create a drop off library, use an existing column or new column that
   will contain a user identifier.
2. Create folders for each person in the drop off library.
3. Set the default value for the tracking column on each folder to that
   users identifier.
4. Create your user libraries for use user and the library name should
   match the user identifier you are using in the drop off folders.
5. Create a workflow that starts on new items added, stores the user
   identfier and uses that to move the item to the list with the same
   name.

I would use a separate workflow for on boarding that provisions the target folders and libraries.

Comment: Thanks Jesus!

For our 7000 employees, that would mean we'd create 7000 FOLDERS in the dropoff library, then create another 7000 LIBRARIES to receive the documents via the organizer rules.

Correct?  That's what you're suggesting?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to dynamically look @ a piece of metadata that was applied to the document when uploaded, then decide where it needs to go after that?  Looks like in the Content Organizer rules or even in Workflows you have to know where the library is located first before you can create the rule?  Are we looking @ CSOM in order to do something this dynamic?

Comment: You can do dynamic lookups in workflows.  You can use the REST API to make calls and return data and then take action on that data.

Comment: This would be via Visual Studios though...correct?  Not via SharePoint Designer...correct?

Comment: Looks like SP Designer is an option for REST API >> http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api-from-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Answer (score 0):

1. Use your Sharepoint Designer and click on open sit.
2. Put the site link (not list link) and press open
3. Go to workflow section
4. Click on List Workflow on the top left and find your
   list/library to relate it. E.g Documents
5. Give a name to your workflow. E.g HR docs
6. Now here you would have to put your conditions and rules. This would a bit too much to explain and require rules to your specific needs